# How can I generate my code to check whether the word is palindrome or not?

Tags: java

```
class Pali {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    String word = "reliefpfpfeiller";
    char[] let = word.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0; i < let.length; i++ ){
        if (let[i] == let[let.length -i]){
            System.out.println("this is palindrome!!!");
        }
    }       
  }
}
```

This is not working and gives this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16
        at Pali.main(Pali.java:6)
```

What can I do to fix the error and make my code work? I want the program to check the words if they are palindrome or not.

Comment: Hint: what is `let.length - i` when `i` is 0?

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong because it will succeed at the first match.

Comment: Should had googled `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` before posting. IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Pali {
    public static void main(String args[]){
       String word = "reliefpfpfeiller";
       char[] let = word.toCharArray();
       for (int i=0; i < let.length / 2; i++ ) {
           if (let[i] != let[let.length - i - 1]){
              System.out.println("this is not palindrome!!!");
              return;
           }
       }
       System.out.println("this is a palindrome!!!");
    }
}
```

- Checking of left and right halfs of word should be only one time, so we **write 'let.length / 2' instead of 'let.length'** in 'if' condition.
- Exception root cause is that you trying to get **'let.length - i'** character: in first iteration you got **let.length - 0 = let.length**, so we should replace it with **'let.length - i - 1'**
- 'if' condition was inverted to get right checking logic

Comment: Care to explain, why?

Comment: You must check only left and right halfs of word, so we write 'let.length / 2' instead of 'let.length' in 'if' condition.

Also, you got exception trying to get 'let.length - i' character: in first iteration you got let.length - 0 = let.length, so we are write there 'let.length - i - 1'

And i inverted your 'if' condition to get right check logic.

Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: @necromancer - Care to explain your edit?  You seem to have removed the output in the "success" case.

Comment: Add explanation to your answer. Directly completing the code won't help future readers.

Comment: @Meiblorn your original use of `break` which i changed to a `return` was a clear bug (FYI)

Comment: You don't ___fix code___ in an edit. See [how to edit.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: thanks, it helped very much but can you explain why you firstly wrote not equal and then the else statment?

Comment: We can write it with 'else' operator if we will use 'break' instead of 'return'
`if (let[i] != let[let.length - i - 1]){
    System.out.println("this is not palindrome!!!");
    break;
  } else if (i == let.length / 2) {
    System.out.println("this is a palindrome!!!");
  }`

Comment: So, why we write != firstly??

Comment: Just for faster exiting from 'for' loop. If we get that letters are not matching, there are not reason to continue loop iterations. If right and left parts are equal, we never enter in this 'if' statement.

Answer (score 6):

If you like lesser code you can use `StringBuilder`:

```
String word = "reliefpfpfeiller";
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(word);
buffer.reverse(); // reverse the letters
if(word.equals(buffer.toString())){
   System.out.println("this is palindrome!!!");
}
```

Comment: Yes, but ... please ... use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Indeed @Seelenvirtuose as long as `synchronization`is not an issue which seems the case here. Let me just edit it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your exception occurs in this line

```
if (let[i] == let[let.length - i]) {
```

because if `i  == 0` then `let.length - 0 == let.length`, and that index doesn't exist. Indices exist always from `0` until `let.length - 1`. So in order to fix it, just write

```
if (let[i] == let[let.length - i]) {
```

Second, you don't have to iterate over all characters of the whole word. You just need to iterate over the first half (if the number of characters is odd, then you need to include the middle character too). That results into `(word.length() / 2) + 1`, because when `word.length()` is odd, then the result of the division by 2 is [floored](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), so in order to include the middle character, you need to add 1.

The code below takes the first half of the characters and compares them to the last half. So in the 0 compares to 3 and 1 compares to 2.

```
0 1 2 3
n o o n
```

In this example, 0 will compare to 4 and 1 to 3. 2 will be compared to 2, which is, of course, always true.

```
0 1 2 3 4
a l u l a
```

(Notice: [alula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alula) is a piece of a bird's wing.)

Here is the code which does the trick.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
    if (word.length() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Word must be non-empty.");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (word.length() / 2) + 1; i++) {
        if (word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(word.length() - i - 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

*PS: In the Dutch language, there are some beautiful words which are a palindrome:*

- *Meetsysteem (measuring system)*
- *Parterretrap (ground floor stairs)*

*Feel free to use them to test abovementioned method.*